# Trying to understand templates and name lookup

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I am trying to understand the following code snippets

Snippet #1

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    static constexpr int VB = T::VD;
};

struct B : A<B>
{
};
```

Neither gcc9 nor clang9 throw an error here.

Q. Why does this code compile? Aren't we instantiating `A<B>` when inheriting from B? There is no VD in B, so shouldn't the compiler throw an error here?

Snippet #2

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    static constexpr auto AB = T::AD; // <- No member named AD in B
};

struct B : A<B>
{
    static constexpr auto AD = 0xD;
};
```

In this case, gcc9 compiles fine but clang9 throws an error saying "No member named AD in B".

Q. Why does it compile with gcc9/why doesn't it compile with clang9?

Snippet #3

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    using TB = typename T::TD;
};

struct B : A<B>
{
    using TD = int;
};
```

Here both clang9 and gcc9 throw an error. gcc9 says "invalid use of incomplete type 'struct B'".

Q. If struct B is incomplete here then why is it not incomplete in snippet #2?

Compiler flags used: `-std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Werror`. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: @xception Isn't `struct B` instantiating `A` with `B`?

Comment: *clang9 throws an error saying "No member named AD in B"*. as `B` is incomplete... But unsure when member should be instantiated..

Comment: @MutableSideEffect oh yes, my bad, read that as a template as well :(

Comment: @Jarod42 then why does gcc compile fine?

Comment: There is declaration and definition of the member. with `auto`, type of `auto` requires the definition of its initializer...

Comment: I have flagged this question as "needing more focus" and the question indeed contains more than one question (hence my conclusion), so why is my flag wrong?

Comment: @Dominique It looks like it's been [used as an audit 15 times so far](/posts/59353546/timeline). Only one of those audits was failed. Based on the answer below, it looks like the sub-questions are tightly coupled, in that they are about very similar things (i.e. explore different aspects of the [same section of the specification](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#temp.inst)). However, I'm not a subject matter expert, so I'd defer to someone who is wrt. making the decision as to the sub-questions being coupled tightly enough to not have the question be too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe these essentially boil down to [[temp.inst]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#temp.inst-2) (emphasis mine):

> **The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions**, default arguments, or *noexcept-specifiers* **of the** class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, **static data members**, member templates, and friends; […]

and [[temp.inst]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#temp.inst-9)

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate […] a static data member of a class template […] unless such instantiation is required.

The wording in the standard concerning implicit template instantiation leaves many details open to interpretation. In general, it would seem to me that you simply cannot rely on parts of a template *not* being instantiated unless the specification explicitly says so. Thus:

#### Snippet #1

> Q. Why does this code compile? Aren't we instantiating A when inheriting from B? There is no VD in B, so shouldn't the compiler throw an error here?

You are instantiating `A<B>`. But instantiating `A<B>` only instantiates the declarations, not the definitions of its static data members. `VB` is never used in a way that would require a definition to exist. The compiler should accept this code.

#### Snippet #2

> Q. Why does it compile with gcc9/why doesn't it compile with clang9?

As pointed out by Jarod42, the declaration of `AB` contains a placeholder type. It would seem to me that the wording of the standard is not really clear on what is supposed to happen here. Does the instantiation of the declaration of a static data member that contains a placeholder type trigger placeholder type deduction and, thus, constitute a use that requires the definition of the static data member? I can't find wording in the standard that would clearly say either yes or no to that. Thus, I would say that both interpretations are equally valid here and, thus, GCC and clang are both right…

#### Snippet #3

> Q. If struct B is incomplete here then why is it not incomplete in snippet #2?

A class type is only complete at the point where you reach the closing `}` of the *class-specifier* [[class.mem]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#mem-6). Thus, `B` is incomplete during the implicit instantiation of `A<B>` in all your snippets. It's just that this was irrelevant for Snippet #1. In Snippet #2, clang did give you an error `No member named AD in B` as a result. Similar to the case of Snippet #2, I can't find wording on when exactly member alias declarations would be instantiated. However, unlike for the definition of static data members, there is no wording in place to explicitly prevent the instantiation of member alias declarations during implicit instantiation of a class template. Thus, I would say that the behavior of both GCC and clang is a valid interpretation of the standard in this case…

Comment: Thanks. In this case, we initialize the static data member within the body. Is the initialization part of the declaration, or part of the definition of the static data member? I was in the impression that if the initialization is within the body, then that's part of the declaration of the static data member. If it's part of the declaration, then your first quote requires immediate instantiation as part of the surrounding implicit instantiation of the class template.

Comment: I looked into the spec and it appears there's a difference between C++14 and C++17 here. In C++14, the `constexpr` static data member was only a declaration. C++17 gained `inline` variables and `constexpr` implies `inline`, and this makes the in-body static data member declaration a definition.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#4.sentence-2 says "The type of a variable declared using a placeholder type is deduced from its initializer. This use is allowed in an initializing declaration ([dcl.init]) of a variable.". Therefore I would argue that the definition of the static data member is required, because it contains the initializer.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Thanks for looking into this! I've been wondering about these questions as well but couldn't find any wording that would be conclusive. Concerning the initialization vs. definition thing, consider a definition of a member function inside the definition of the class template. Such a definition is also a declaration and there are no other declarations. Yet, implicit instantiation of the class template will only instantiate a declaration but not the definition of the member function. Why would the same thing not be true for static data members?

Comment: if there's nothing that requires the definiton, the definition is not instantiated. But in the `auto` case, the rule says that the declaration must be an initializing declaration. This can only be the case if it's known that the declaration is a definition (as far as I know.. I've been out of lawyer-land for a while). In the past, there was a similar case and http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#2.sentence-3 was added, where a declaration that's a definition is instantiated as "being known to be a definition" without actually instantiating the definition.

Comment: However, I don't see any such rule for auto that would allow the placeholder-type rules to "know" that it's an initializing declaration, without fully instantiating the definition.

Comment: Actually, I'm quite a bit confused about the meaning of "declarations, but not of the definitions," of `constexpr` inline static data members in C++17. What's the non-definition parts of them? The whole thing is a definition! It's a definition because it doesn't occur in http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#2 . If we remove the initializer, it's still a definition because it's still `constexpr` and implicitly inline! So maybe to instantiate the "declarations, but not of the definitions" of them doesn't make much sense? Don't know, it's over my head!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb yes, I'm also very confused. The more I dig, the more confused I get by the wording I find -.- However, consider the case of a member function defined in a class template. That definition is also the only declaration of the member function. There is no declaration that is not a definition there either. If we take [temp.inst]/2 as literally instantiating the exact declaration that declared these entities, then implicit instantiation of a member function the declaration of which was also a definition would mean that a definition is instantiated!?

Comment: This is clearly not what happens or what would be intended to happen since depending on this not happening has been standard practise since basically forever. The standard library itself depends on this not happening all over the place…

Comment: The only interpretation of [temp.inst]/2 that leads to something that makes sense to me is to take it as meaning that not the literally exact declarations that declared the entities in questions are instantiated, but rather that declarations that are not definitions are synthesized for these entities during implicit instantiation of the class template…I seriously hope someone can provide an explanation to bring some clarity here…

Comment: yes I think so. For function definitions, there is http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.pre-11 and http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct.def.general-2.sentence-1 which apparently are supposed to let implementors know what part is the "declaring" part and which is the "defining" part. For data members however, I found no such thing.